# Azure in-role cache very slow

Tags: performance, optimization, azure, azure-caching

I have an azure cloud service consisting of one web role with azure cache co-located with the same role. I am seeing cache accesses to be too slow. Each get call takes ~800 ms. What could be wrong? What should i look at for optimization?

Comment: Though I haven't actively monitored cache performance but one thing we noticed is that if we rely on caching service's in-built serializer/deserializer we saw some slowness. Could that be the issue?

Comment: What size of the VM and how many calls are you making to the cache? In-role cache seems to run optimally using a medium size dedicated instance. But a number of factors could cause possible saturation.

Answer (score 0):

More data is needed.

Whats your object size ? Are only the puts taking time or the gets are equally bad ?

Is the slowness only seen on devfabric or on actual deployments too ?

Whats the role size ?

Colocation brings with it CPU boundness with your current app, is it hogging all the CPU ? Colocation was not supported with XS machines. Apart from the serializer, the machine itself could be the cause for slowness.